# B-spline surfaces fitting references

Tags: geometry, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, spline

I am looking for **reference** papers / publications regarding **b-spline / NURBS surfaces fitting** (I think I have noticed NURBS fitting is not very widespread so I guess most references will be related to b-splines surfaces fitting). **The NURBS book** by ***Les Piegl*** is a reference for everything related to splines but it literally stops at surface approximation.

I have obviously already googled the subject, but I am actually willing to understand what the reference publication in the domain are.